# What are the various technicians and their effects?

Tags: sky-force-reloaded

Update 1.5.0 of Sky Force Reloaded added prestige points (a kind of "achievement points" that you get for your accumulated totals of kills, rescues and other metrics). Get enough of these and they in turn start unlocking technicians, that grant you some benefit while playing, and can be swapped out at the start of the mission similar to how planes can be.

What are the various technicians that can be unlocked and what effects do they have?

Answer (score 6):

There appears to be eight technicians to unlock and so far these are the first seven:

1. Gringo Star: "Fills a random crate with a bunch of extra stars" - seems self explanatory
2. Kate Brush: "Paints over your first scratch, that's one more chance to stay untouched" - the first time you get hit, it doesn't count. Good for getting those medals!
3. Burton Panic: "Has a few power-ups of his own" - "randomly" triggers additional power-ups during the mission (without using up yours). So far, he appears to have a certain pattern that he follows, so there's specific places in each mission where he will use shield, megabomb or laser. Not sure if it's actually random or triggered by the game state at that point somehow (i.e. 'enough bullets nearby to trigger shield')
4. Lucy Clover: "Brings good fortune (in all aspects)" - not entirely sure about this one, but I suspect that she both causes crates to have better loot (maybe more cards similar to what Ace of Spades does?) and to cause 'Lucky Shield' to activate more often - update: It seems that with Lucy Clover, the first time you get hit consistently triggers a lucky shield, effectively making this technician as good or better than Kate Brush.
5. Slo Mo Chan: "Slows down hostile bullets". It's self explanatory. Slo Mo Chan will create some kind of "Aura" (only) in the beginning of a level. He is also capable to slow down the infamous EMP of stage 5.
6. Tase Mebro: "Strikes nearby enemies with a lightning bolt" - You can see a video of this in action [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zrf3qX9B5f8&t=105)
7. Holo Granny: "Deploys decoys on the field" - From time to time creates temporary holograms of your ship that last a few seconds.

   8. Hayes Core: "Helps to get high scores" - each box gives 2.000 points (instead of zero) and the bomb-, laser- and chield-load-places are now score-load-places. The longer you load them, the more points you get and the faster they raise. Max points for each load-place ~ 4.000 points.

[image: The Technicians]

Comment: what's the best technicians? (pc version)

Comment: @giò it depends on the level you are playing. Foe example, if you are aiming to rescue all humans, slo mo chan will be best(imho)

Answer (score 1):

"Lucy Clover" will always activate shield when you're about to die.

Answer (score 1):

6. Tase Mebro

Finally unlocked this one. I'm hopefully going to unlock the next one within the next 2 weeks. Number 8 technician cannot be gotten because it is impossible to acquire 200 medals at the current moment
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: holo granny]

Just unlocked Holo Granny. She places temporal holograms of your ship on the field from time to time. Holograms lasts some seconds.

Comment: Awesome! I've added the info to the list - have an upvote! :)

Answer (score 0):

5th is "slo mo chan"
Slow downs hostile bullets

Comment: Hi Mehmet!  Good information but it would work better if you added it into the current answer! :) This answer alone is missing context, but editing the  list right above to include this will greatly help! (and get you rep as well!)

Answer (score 0):

The last wingman, Hayes Core, which helps getting high scores.